# Aysmptotic Analysis Proof

Tags: complex-analysis, algorithms

Not sure how to prove the following. [Link to Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoraa.png)

$$e^x=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\frac{x^i}{i!}+\Theta(x^m)\,,$$
for all $m=1,2,\cdots$

Comment: Taylor's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $m=1$
this is
$e^x = 1+\Theta(x)$
which is not true for large $x$.

You need a restriction such as
$|x| \le 1$.